# R: how to optimize multiple pattern count over multiple strings?

Tags: r, string, optimization, count, lapply

I have (1) a set of sentences, (2) a set of keywords, and (3) scores (real numbers) for each keyword. I need to assign scores to sentences, where the score of a sentence = sum_over_keywords(keyword count within sentence * keyword score).

Reproducible example:

```
library(stringi)
# generate 200 synthetic sentences containing 15 5-character words each
set.seed(7122016)
sentences_splitted = lapply(1:200, function(x) stri_rand_strings(15, 5))

# randomly select some words from the sentences as our keywords
set.seed(7122016)
keywords = unlist(lapply(sentences_splitted, function(x) if(sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),size=1,prob=c(0.2,0.8))) x[1]))
len_keywords = length(keywords)

# assign scores to keywords
set.seed(7122016)
my_scores = round(runif(len_keywords),4)
```

Now, scoring the sentences:

```
res = system.time(replicate(100,
    unlist(lapply(sentences_splitted, function (x)
        sum(unlist(lapply(1:len_keywords, function(y) 
            length(grep(paste0("\\<",keywords[y],"\\>"),x))*my_scores[y]
        )))))))
```

I tried to optimize the code as much as I could, but it is still **very slow**:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  11.81    0.01   11.89
```

I need to repeat this operation more than 200,000 times... Is there anything faster than `length(grep(paste0("\\<",keywords[y],"\\>"),x))`? Should I use something else than nested `lapply`'s?

NOTES:

- I already plan to use the four cores of my laptop in parallel, so
  what I really need is to make the basic chunk shown above faster.
- I am happy to call C/C++/Fortran code from R if someone offers
  a script (unfortunately I don't know these languages).

Comment: What result do you get from `res`? I'm getting all zeroes from your example with dimensions 200 x 100. Can you check the output of the example?

Comment: @PierreLafortune I started a new R session and double checked. I am still getting the same output: i.e., `6.23    0.00    6.32 `

Comment: I'm sorry. I should specify. I get that the time appears when you surround the `replicate` function with system time. But remove the `system.time` wrapper and you will see that the actual function is not working. It is producing all zeroes.

Comment: @PierreLafortune Thanks for noticing. I have fixed this issue and edited the question accordingly. But now, with `length(grep(paste0("\\<",keywords[y],"\\>"),x))` it takes even more time

Comment: You use `replicate`, why? Why are you doing the same operation 100 times? It doesn't make sense. It's the same expression each time. We use `replicate` when we want to repeat a process that changes each time, not to do the exact same thing each round. Check your output. Notice that each column is identical to every other.

Comment: I get your point. I am using `replicate` to compute efficiency, because it is more reliable to time an operation repeated many times than just once. But that does not change my question anyway

Comment: @PierreLafortune Since my question was about speed, I was expecting timing on my reproducible example, and what you showed was instead that your function did return weighted scores. This is why I thought you had misunderstood my question. Anyway, it would be interesting to add to your answer why your proposed solution is faster and how much faster it is (showing system.time() output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can name the `my_scores` vector with the keywords. Remember, R allows for subsetting by names. So if we can get the matched words we can get the scores too:

```
names(my_scores) <- keywords
res <- sapply(sentences_splitted, function(x) sum(my_scores[x[x %in% keywords]]))
```

That is all that is needed. We can test it out with a smaller testable example:

```
#Create sentences
sentences_splitted <- list(c("abc", "def", "ghi", "abc"), c("xyz", "abc", "mno", "xyz"))
keywords <- c("abc", "xyz")
my_scores <- c(10,20)

#We should expect
10 * 2 #first sentence
10 * 1 and 20 * 2 #second sentence
#Expected result
[1] 20 50

#Check that function works as expected
names(my_scores) <- keywords
sapply(sentences_splitted, function(x) sum(my_scores[x[x %in% keywords]]))
[1] 20 50
```

Comment: thank you, but my question is about efficiency. My function works as expected (see the edit I made to my question).

Comment: I give up. What on earth has happened to this site?

Comment: @Antoine This is probably one of the most efficient solutions using base R. Far under a second for more than 100 replicates.

Comment: indeed it is much faster. Thank you @PierreLafortune!